# Can't setup monitor after reconnecting ThinkPad T570 to USB-C dock

Tags: arch-linux, xrandr, laptop, dock

I've got two monitors connected via DisplayPort to the dock. `xrandr` displays the external monitors as `DP1-1` and `DP1-2` and the laptop as `eDP1`.

I set up my monitors with the following in ~/.xprofile:

```
xrandr --output eDP1 --same-as DP1-1
xrandr --output DP1-2 --right-of DP1-1
```

This works fine. When disconnecting the laptop from the dock the laptop screen does the right thing, reverting to a single monitor. When reconnecting the laptop DP1-1 shows up, but DP1-2 remains blank. `. ~/.xprofile` changes nothing, and no error message is printed. I tried reconfiguring using [the `--crtc` option](https://askubuntu.com/a/157465/10371), but all I ended up with were complaints that crtc-1 (or something similar) was not configured correctly. After trying a couple things I got "xrandr: cannot find output 0x46", which I can't find any precedence for.

After reconnecting the monitors have the same names ("DP1-1" and "DP1-2") and both of them are shown as "connected" by `xrandr`.

Comment: I may not have direct answers but few pointers which I want you to try. 1. (Mons package)[https://github.com/Ventto/mons] 2. adding hotplug configuration for monitor. and running xrandr when detected.

Comment: you can try https://github.com/codingtony/udev-monitor-hotplug. I feel this is better way because this way we can always execute when some device plugged in or out. whereas when we do it using  ~/.xprofile it will execute only once on start of x-server. I am not claiming it cannot be done that way. just this is more convinient way to write logic(this is just my personal preferance).

Comment: Are the monitors named the same after reconnecting them?

Comment: Ok... you are an experienced user, so I think the more likely it is a: new-hardware+double GPU+USB-C+multi-monitor-setup = kernel/driver bug or missing feature -> try to open a bug report

Comment: @mattia.b89 After filing probably hundreds of bug reports in open source projects I haven't the faintest idea what or even where to report this issue. Is it a bug in X, the Intel driver, `xrandr`, or some other component? And in my experience the amount of work involved in writing such a bug report which will be fixed is about the same as learning to program it myself.

Comment: @l0b0 Did you ever to figure this out? I'm having the same issue (Thinkpad T490, USB-C dock 40A9, manjaro-i3).

Comment: Nah @samuelkf, it still happens. Fortunately for me I don't have to do this very often, but that also means I can't really spend a lot of time looking into it.

Comment: @l0b0 fair play. I'll report back if I make any progress on it myself.

Comment: So... if I manually set the mode for each display [as suggested here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227876/how-to-set-custom-resolution-using-xrandr-when-the-resolution-is-not-available-i), they start working again. Interestingly, I still get the same 'configure crtc failed' error, but the displays come back to life.

Comment: @l0b0 You still have access to the problem? ;-)  I might be able to help, as might my answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/732040/9417) and [there](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/736679)

Comment: @RobertSiemer Nah, different software and hardware now. Thanks for following up though!

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, it sometimes works to issue `xrandr --auto` after connecting to the dock again. This brings up the external monitor 3 out of 10 times at least.
Also logging out and then in brings the monitor back to life.