# xrandr: Configure crtc 1 failed

Tags: xrandr, hdmi

I'm trying to connect my laptop to a TV screen via HDMI. Here is the output of `xrandr`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 190mm
   1366x768      60.01*+
   1280x720      59.86    60.00    59.74  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00    59.90    59.82  
   960x540       60.00    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00    59.92    59.57  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       59.51    60.00    58.99  
   680x384       60.00  
   640x360       59.84    59.32    60.00  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    48.04    59.94  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1400x1050     59.95  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x576i      50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x480i      60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Now when I try to use the screen, I always get the following error:

```
$ xrandr --output HDMI1 --auto
xrandr: Configure crtc 1 failed
```

I have already tried using different modes and the other crtc, still get the same error.

EDIT: Driver info

```
$ lspci -k | grep -A 3 -E "(VGA|3D)"
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display (rev 0e)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 161d
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```

EDIT 2:
So I figured out that the TV seems to be the problem, as every other screen I tried works just fine. I also found a workaround that kinda does the job for me: create a custom mode with `--newmode`, add it to the HDMI1 output with `--addmode`, so that i can enable the output while unplugged and then plug the cable in. Not really sure why this works though, so any explanation would still be very welcome.

Comment: Have you checked similar question here
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/485026/xrandr-fails-randomly-with-configure-crtc-x-failed-on-dock-with-multiple-monit

Comment: I did, and nothing worked. arandr just reports the same message.