# Can't set the resolution to 1080 on a VGA to HDMI adapter on Debian 10 (Thinkpad X220)

Tags: debian, display, hdmi, vga

I've tried this :

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xrandr#Permanently_adding_undetected_resolutions

Here I was advised on the Debian IRC channel to change the path of the config file to: `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` instead of `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-monitor.conf` as per the ArchWiki.
However, the person who was helping me out vanished.

and also this : [How to set custom resolution using xrandr when the resolution is not available in 'Display Settings'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227876/how-to-set-custom-resolution-using-xrandr-when-the-resolution-is-not-available-i)

none of the above worked.

Using arandr instead I see that the maximum available resolution is 1024x768 which is weird considering that the "manual" says it can support up to 1080p 60Hz which is what I want.

Mind helping me out ?

Comment: Do you have proper graphics drivers?

Comment: @user1794469    I use a Thinkpad X220 and I never had graphics issues until trying to the connect to the TV here. According to the Debian wiki it works out of the box and I believe it. Should have included that I use a Thinkpad , will edit the tittle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Debian, the default directory that contains `xorg.conf` files is indeed `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/`. This would be the correct location to place custom X settings.

Here is the configuration file you need to force a specific resolution (and have none other to choose from!). Save it in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-monitor.conf` and reboot. Note, I generated the modeline with the command `cvt 1280 1080`.

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "VGA1"
    Modeline "1280x1080_60.00"  115.00  1280 1368 1496 1712  1080 1083 1093 1120 -hsync +vsync
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Device     "Device0"
    Monitor    "VGA1"
    SubSection "Display" 
        Modes  "1280x1080_60.00" 
    EndSubSection 
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "Device0"
    Driver "intel"
EndSection
```

If this still doesn't work, then you VGA adapter probably doesn't support this mode, despite what the manual says.

Comment: Indeed, doing this and changing the relevant Modeline only improved things slightly but still didn't fix the problem. The vertical resolution was better used but I had black bars that were of varying thickness depending on which HDMI port was being used. To make sure it's due to the adapter I connected both the TV and the adapter to a Win 10 machine and indeed the most it could do was around 1600 -ish with no ability to successfuly scale up to FHD, where the system couldn't even register the proper numbers but rather some close ones.

Case closed, it's the adapter's fault.

Thx