# External monitor stuck on "Unknown display" 1024x768 - Fedora 34

Tags: fedora, display, desktop

Using a fresh install of Fedora 34 Workstation edition(GNOME) on a dell latitude 7400 laptop, I'm struggling to make my external display to work, an Asus ROG PG278Q 27".
Connecting through the USB-C port, the display shows up in the system settings as an "unknown display" and the resolution is capped at 1024x768.

Things I already did:

- updated all packages with `dnf update`
- tried setting the resolution with xrandr, following [this resolution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227876/how-to-set-custom-resolution-using-xrandr-when-the-resolution-is-not-available-i)

  - `xrandr --newmode "2560x1440-144ghz"  808.75  2560 2792 3072 3584  1440 1443 1448 1568 -hsync +vsync`
  - `xrandr --addmode XWAYLAND1 "2560x1440-144ghz"`
  - `xrandr --output XWAYLAND1 --mode "2560x1440-144ghz"` - gives me "X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
    "

system info:

- Graphics: Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 620 (WHL GT2)
- Windowing system: Wayland
- GNOME Version: 40.4
- `lspci | grep VGA` output: `00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation WhiskeyLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics 620] (rev 02)`

This is my first time in many years switching to a linux desktop, this display used to work on my previous windows 10 instalation and it also worked in my (brief) rocky linux 8 installation.

Comment: I have the exact same issue with an AMD RX 6600 and a PG278Q. It looks like [there's a longstanding bug about it](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues/615). Its an extremely annoying bug, it essentially means that my monitor is useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to finally get this fixed by changing my "Windowing System" from Wayland (default on gnome) to X11, then following the xrandr guide I posted in the original question.

You can check your windowing system in "settings > about" and you can change the windowing system when you log out and there should be the option on the right-hand bottom side of the screen where you input your password