# Can't change my resolution

Tags: linux, manjaro

Just to say I'm new to Linux.

I just installed Manjaro with KDE Plasma. Tried running a game through Lutris and it changed my resolution 800x600. Now I can't change it to my resolution of 1680x1050.

When I run xrandr I get this:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP-0 connected primary 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 470mm x 300mm
   1680x1050     59.95 +
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02* 
   1280x800      59.81  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I try `xrandr -s 1680x1050`

and it says `Size 1680x1050 not found in available modes`

What do I do?

EDIT: Maybe I should mention that the resolution is good on the login screen and then when I log in it gets smaller.

Comment: Could you try `xrandr -s 1` ? Or even `xrandr --output DP-0 -s 1` ?

Comment: The first command makes my screen go black for a second and then nothing changes. The second one doesn't do anything.

Comment: "Maybe I should mention that the resolution is good on the login screen and then when I log in it gets smaller." do you mean that restarting computer doesn't solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set custom resolution using xrandr when the resolution is not available in 'Display Settings'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227876/how-to-set-custom-resolution-using-xrandr-when-the-resolution-is-not-available-i)

Comment: Oh my god I never knew there was 'Display Settings', I swear I tried looking everywhere it just never came across my eyes I guess. Nevertheless, I can set my resolution using it, thank you.